# Return SQL query errors in PHP file

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

UPD: **CLOSED**. Duplicate found and typos in my original question

I am using this code and I want to get a message if there is an error with my SQL query :

```
$Db = mysqli_init();
$Db->options(MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE, true);
$Db->real_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname, 3306);

// Creation of first SQL query
$sql = ('select sum('.$metric1.') as t1metric from '.$table1.' WHERE '.$date1.' between "'.$start_date.'" AND "'.$end_date.'"');
$query = $Db->query($sql);

if ($Db->error) 
{
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $Db->error);
}
```

and I receive this error when I run the php file :

> Call to a member function query() on a non-object

Comment: You should use `$Db` instead `$mysqli`, as above you define `$Db = mysqli_init();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$mysqli->query($query);
```

Replace with:

```
 $Db->query($query);
```

Answer (score 2):

use the following

```
$Db->query($sql);
```

instead of

```
$mysqli->query($query);
```